# Trying to Predict Missing Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to impute missing values, not with zeros or means, but with ML predicted results.  I'm testing my idea on the standard 'Titanic' dataset, which has around 80% of the age records filled in, but around 20% are missing.  How can I fill in missing values with the predicted results from a simple linear regression model?  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg = LinearRegression()

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\seaborn-data\\titanic.csv')
print(data)
list(data)
data.dtypes


data_with_null = data[['survived','pclass','sibsp','parch','fare','age']]

data_without_null = data_with_null.dropna()
train_data_x = data_without_null.iloc[:,:5]
train_data_y = data_without_null.iloc[:,5]

linreg.fit(train_data_x,train_data_y)

test_data = data_with_null.iloc[:,:5]
age = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))

# check for nulls
data_with_null.apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()),axis=0)
```

Everything works up to this point, but when I try to 'fillna', I get errors.

```
data_with_null.age.fillna(age,inplace=True)
```

The line of code directly above shows this error:

TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame"

```
data_with_null['age'].fillna(data_with_null[data_with_null['age'].isnull()].apply(axis=1),inplace=True)
```

Similarly, the line of code above shows this error:

TypeError: `apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

Comment: `data_with_null['age'].fillna(data_with_null[data_with_null['age'].isnull()].apply(axis=1),inplace=True)` Here in the `.apply()` function you are missing one argument, it's required a function like you do in `data_with_null.apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()),axis=0)`

Comment: For first error, try:
`age = list(linreg.predict(test_data))` instead of `age = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))`

Comment: `data_with_null.age.fillna(age,inplace=True)` here you are passing a dataframe, just use one column of the DF

Comment: Oh, yes, now I see it!!  Thanks everyone!!